# Inject Spring Beans from resources.groovy into integration test for a Grails 3 Service

Tags: grails, spock

I am trying to write an integration test for a service that has a spring bean injected into it. The spring bean is defined in `resources.groovy`. The bean that my service is using does not appear to be getting injected in my integration test, but it gets injected fine when i run `grails run-app`.

Here is a minimal failing example:

`grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
  myBean(Object){}
}
```

`grails-app/services/MyService.groovy`

```
class MyService {
  def myBean

  def serviceMethod(){
    myBean.class.simpleName
  }
}
```

`grails-app/src/integration-test/groovy/MyServiceSpec.groovy`

```
@Integration
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
  def myService

  when:
  def myBean = myService.myBean

  then:
  myBean != null
}
```

Grails version info:

```
$ grails -v
| Grails Version: 3.1.9 
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_92
```

Update:

Spring seems to inject other services just fine. If I declare another service inside of `MyService`, it gets injected.

```
class MyService {
  def myBean
  def myOtherService

  def serviceMethod(){
    myBean.class.simpleName
  }
}
```

Comment: Integration should not look like what you have. Add a test case then use `when` and `then`.

Comment: What do you mean "Integration should not look like what you have". My test case does have when and then...

Comment: Hello. Any luck with this issue? Did you found any way to make it work, or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party on this one... But, for future readers, try setting `grails.gorm.autowire` to `true` in your `application.yml`

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of peculiar things about your example, e.g.

```
beans = {
  myBean(Object){}
}
```

I can't imagine why you'd want to create a bean of type `Object`, but maybe this is a simplification you made for the purposes of the example and the real bean has a different type.

```
@Integration
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
  def myService

  when:
  def myBean = myService.myBean

  then:
  myBean != null
}
```

This test boils down to testing whether dependency injection works, which means your testing Spring/Grails rather than your own code. This is not something you should be testing IMO.

Anyhow to fix your problem I think you just need to add an `@Autowired` annotation

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*

@Integration
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  def myService

  when:
  def myBean = myService.myBean

  then:
  myBean != null
}
```

Comment: Hey there. The whole point of the example is to show that dependency injection is not working :). The test is just a contrived example to demonstrate the problem.

Adding `@Autowired` does not make any difference unfortunately. The service does not get injected, myBean is still null.